# Why is my this.x increment getting bigger each time?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to implement simple movement for an object 'player' of class Player, which was instantiated with `player = new Player(40, 40, 15);` in function setup() of my JavaScript file.
The following code is included within my draw() function, and it correctly recognises keyboard inputs for D, A and Space.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
      function checkKeyPress(key){
        if (key.keyCode == "68"){
          player.rightMove();
        } else if (key.keyCode == "65"){
          player.leftMove();
        } else if (key.keyCode == "32"){
          player.jump();
        }
      }
      player.show();
```

My problem though comes with the following code:

```
constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }

  rightMove() {
    this.x++;
    if (this.x >= 980){
      this.x--
    }
  }
  leftMove() {
    this.x--;
    if (this.x <= 20){
      this.x++
    }
```

This is within the Player class structure, and it correctly moves the object right/left/up via incrementing/decrementing the x/y value as necessary.
And below is part of the show() function:

```
ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*1.7);
```

However, the problem I have is that every time I execute one of the movement functions by pressing a key, it seems that the value my x/y value in/decrements by is increasing. Every time I press one of the keys it moves the object more and more, not just the '1' change it should be with '++' or '--'.
I'm not sure why the change is increasing with each press - how can I fix this to only change the x or y by 1 each time?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: below is my function draw(), which includes show() at the bottom once.

```
function draw() {
  background(220);
  image(BG,0,0,width,height);
  window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);
  function checkKeyPress(key){
    if (key.keyCode == "68"){
      player.rightMove();
    } else if (key.keyCode == "65"){
      player.leftMove();
    } else if (key.keyCode == "32"){
      player.jump();
    }
  }
  player.show();
}
```

This results in the player object moving left/right/up when the correct key is pressed/held, by drawing a new ellipse at the new coordinates, as below:

```
show() {
    stroke('#800080');
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill('#800080')
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*1.7);
  }
```

Comment: `how can I fix this to only change the x or y by 1 each time?` by using `keyup` event instead of `keydown`

Comment: Are you calling `window.addEventListener` multiple times, eg.  You don't call this in player.show do you?

Comment: Please provide code with which the problem can be reproduced. As it stands `player.show();` is just executed once. So nothing is moving. Since you say it moves, there is essential code missing. There could be several things wrong.

Comment: You must not do the `window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress, false);` from inside `draw`. Put it (and the `checkKeyPress` declaration) outside, at the top level of your code.